# Website errors social media links "refuse to connect"

Tags: web, hyperlink

After adding social media links in my HTML file and I click on them I only receive an error that states: 
Facebook refused to connect.

'''Facebook'''

Comment: <a href="https://www.facebook.com/evercrownph/"><i class="im im-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Facebook</span></a>

Comment: Code example please

Comment: I posted one in the comments

Answer (score 0):

While hosting the app you might have end up with masking option.
Just simple solution, you need to use target="_blank" attribute in your anchor tag.

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/yourName" target="_blank" class="facebook"><i class="bx bxl-facebook"></i></a>`

That's it. Let me know if it helped you.